# "File ended while scanning use of \@ref." error in LaTeX

Tags: errors

I am using the MikTex distribution of LaTeX and the Eledmac package for line numbering of a critical edition. No previous problems with this setup --  until today.

WHEN I USE THE \beginnumbering COMMAND, THE TEXT FAILS TO COMPILE AND I GET THE FOLLOWING MESSAGE IN THE OUTPUT CONSOLE:

Runaway argument?
[\@ref [0][]\@ref [0][\@ref [0][]\@ref [0][\@ref [0][]\@ref [0][\@ref \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@ref.
 
                \par 
l.23 \beginnumbering

THE ERROR CONSOLE GIVES ME THE FOLLOWING MESSAGE:

File ended while scanning use of \@ref.
 
                \par 
l.23 \beginnumbering

I have been trashing the .aux files (at the prompt) between attempts, but no success. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a small complete document that makes the error, otherwise it is very hard to offer any help.

Comment: Such errors are usually due to missing arguments, or `{` without a closing `}` somewhere. If there is a `\beginnumbering` there might have to be a corresponding `\endnumbering` perhaps?